# git command to see both logs and tags

Tags: git

When calling `git log` I see all my changes, and when I call `git tag` I see all tags, but what way can I call `git` to see both logs and tags, so I can see between which two tags in the given branch I had made given change?

Preferably I would like to have one command that would interlace logs and tags. The worst case would be a need to call for each of the tag request to get a list of changes, for our repository contains thousands of tags...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git log --decorate`.

From [git-log(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> ```
> --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
>
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown.
> If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/,
> refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/ will not be printed.
> If full is specified, the full ref name (including prefix)
> will be printed. If auto is specified, then if the output
> is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short
> were given, otherwise no ref names are shown.
> The default option is short.
> ```

Some example output:

> ```
> commit e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5 (tag: v2.9.3, origin/maint)
> Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
> Date:   Fri Aug 12 09:17:51 2016 -0700
>
>     Git 2.9.3
>
>     Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
> ```

Comment: Thank you jjlin. We were using pre 1.8 version of git, and I did not have this option available there.!